# Phonegap plugins not working

Tags: javascript, iphone, plugins, cordova

Phonegap plugins not working in **Phonegap cordova-1.5.0** in **iPhone**. I added the plugin for date picker and one anohe plugin for making phonecall. 
I used the plugins from
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone.

Any one have any idea about this issue??
I just added the external JS file and called it directly. Do I need to make any changes in the plist or somewhere else. **Can anyone tell me the steps to use the Phonegap Plugin in iPhone.?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the PhoneGap version that is compatible with the plugin structure (there were changes around 2.0, and Version 1.5 is pretty old).  For the latest architecture, check here for details:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

For the older plugin architecture, check here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-ios.html

Depending on the version, yes, you may need to edit the .plist files in your Xcode project.  You also have to add the native files to the Xcode project, not just the JavaScript.